# What kind of redirection is >>&?

Tags: io-redirection, csh

I'm looking at a cron file that has the following line:

```
35  0 * * * /bin/csh -c "/home/abc/.cshrc;/home/abc/appTools/bin/xxx.pl >>& /home/abc/appTools/log/xxx.cronlog"
```

Is this another form of redirecting STDOUT and STDERR, like 2>&1 ?  Is there any difference between **>>&** and **2>&1** ? This command seems to be working, unless xxx.cronlog does not already exist.

Comment: csh and bash have slightly different I/O redirection formats....notice this is a csh command.

Comment: Yes, that is why I tagged it "/csh".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't even `csh`, but the manpage says that it's the same thing like `&>>` in `bash` and family—that is open for appending (the `>>`) and also redirect `stderr` instead of just `stdout`.

The forms involving '&' route the diagnostic output into the specified file as well as the standard output. name is expanded in the same way as '<' input filenames are.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh:

> The forms involving '&' route the diagnostic output into the specified
>   file as well as the standard output. name is expanded in the same way
>   as '<' input filenames are.
>
> >> name
>
> >>& name
>
> >>! name
>
> >>&! name
>
> Like '>', but appends output to the end of name. If the shell variable noclobber is set, then it is an error for the file not
>   to exist, unless one of the '!' forms is given.

Comment: Thanks for the bang (!) hint. That may solve my problem.

Comment: No need to thank me. Just make sure you accept the answer so that I can get my green points. :D

Comment: The bang (!) does make sure the redirection ">>&" always writes out the log file, even if the file does not exist. Otherwise, the cron would not execute. One very old bug fixed...